# Function overloading and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have classes Bulldog and Labrador which publicly derive from base class Dog, and I have a function, e.g. a method of a different class, called reward, and I want it to produce different results for objects of class Dog and Bulldog, or for objects of class Bulldog and Labrador. What is the best way of doing this for a C++ developer?

I understand that if Dog has any virtual functions, then I can use `dynamic_cast` for this purpose. Is that something you would recommend? If not, what do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: If you have virtual function, you don't have to do any cast, that's how polymorphism work. Said that, you should first study what polymorphism is, which is not something related to C++ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward approach would be to delegate, using polymorphism, from the `reward(const Dog& dog)` function (free function/other class) to a virtual function of the `Dog` interface, using a provided `Dog` reference that can dispatch virtual `Dog` methods polymorpically. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dog {
    Dog() {}
    virtual ~Dog() {}
    virtual void reward() const { 
        std::cout << "Default dog reward.\n"; 
    }
};

struct Bulldog : public Dog {
    Bulldog() {}
    ~Bulldog() override {}
    void reward() const override {
        std::cout << "Bulldog reward.\n"; 
    }
};

void reward(const Dog& dog) {
    dog.reward();    
}

int main() {
    reward(Dog{});     // Default dog reward.
    reward(Bulldog{}); // Bulldog reward.
    return 0;
}
```